# サーバー上の.htaccessファイルがFTPソフトでの接続時に表示されない

Tags: ftp

wordpressのサーバー移転の作業をするために、移転元のサーバー内のデータを取り出したいのです。

FTPソフトで移転元サーバーへ接続して確認すると、ルートディレクトリ下に、.htaccessが表示されずファイルのダウンロードが行えません。
使用しているFTPソフトはFileZillaで、隠しファイルを表示する設定は行っていますが表示されません。

[filezillaのドットファイルを表示する方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/camomile_cafe/items/7bc7a0df829a27bb5869)

この状態ですと、.htaccessファイルのダウンロード及び、移転先へのアップロードが出来ず困っています。

SSHでの接続の場合は、ルートディレクトリ下に、表示されますのでファイル自体はあると認識しています。

以上の状況ですが、対策等ありましたらご教授いただけないでしょうか？（可能であればFTPソフトにて.htaccessファイルのダウンロードとアップロードをしたいです）

◆作業環境-----------------

●使用PC:Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6

●FTPソフト：FilleZilla Pro 3.46.3

●移転元サーバー：Google Cloud Engine
OS:Debian (9.9)
ソフトウェア:Apache (2.4.25)
PHP (7.0.33)
WordPress (5.2.1)

Comment: FTPサーバは何をお使いですか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。FTPサーバーとは、移転元サーバーの事ではないでしょうか？例えばどのようなサーバーがありますでしょうか？

Comment: 移転元サーバにインストールされている、FTPサーバのソフトウェアのことです。vsftpdとかproftpdとかwuftpdとか。

Comment: 表示されないのではなく、ファイルが存在しないのではないでしょうか。FTPでのアクセス先とSSHでのアクセス先とが同一ディレクトリなのかをまず確認する必要があると思います。

Comment: 移転元のサーバはGCPのGCEです。調べてみたのですが特定できませんでした。クラウドのサーバーの場合も必ずFTPサーバーがインストールされていますでしょうか？自分ではFTPサーバーをインストールはしていません。filezillaでFTP接続するときはSFTPにて行っています。

Comment: SSHでの接続の際は、ファイルが確認できます。ディレクトリの場所も確認していますので、ファイル自体は存在している事は確認しています。

Comment: SSHでログインできているのなら、.htaccessを含むディレクトリを丸ごとアーカイブしてしまい、FTPで取得する…といった方法もワークアラウンドとして考えられます。

Comment: 今回の問題が解決できましたので、コメントさせてもらいます。filleZillaの設定の仕方に不足がありました。こちら（http://www.kitami.tv/2015/05/filezilla.html）の記事を参考に設定する事で、FTPソフト使用時にも、隠しファイルを表示させる事ができました。コメントでのご協力ありがとうございました。

Comment: 解決した場合にはコメント欄ではなく、ぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください (スタック・オーバーフローでは自己回答も歓迎です)。

Answer (score 0):

FilleZillaの設定を確認し、必要であれば設定を変更する必要があります。

1：[filezillaのドットファイルを表示する方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/camomile_cafe/items/7bc7a0df829a27bb5869)

2：[MacのFTPクライアントのFileZillaでローカルの隠しファイルを表示させない方法](http://www.kitami.tv/2015/05/filezilla.html)